# Error in Connecting Oracledb from node js

Tags: node.js, express, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

C:\Users\ramachandran.s>**npm install oracledb**

> oracledb@1.2.0 install C:\Users\ramachandran.s\node_modules\oracledb
>   node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\ramachandran.s\node_modules\oracledb>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\node_
modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebui
ld
**C:\Users\ramachandran.s\node_modules\oracledb\build\binding.sln : error MSB3411
: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is no
t installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 200
8 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.**

What am i missing , please help

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error message, you need to install either the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 or Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  The oracledb Node.JS package uses the Oracle OCI libraries, and they are compiled when you install the package.

I run oracledb on Linux and OSX, so I'm not sure, but you might want to see if the error message goes away after installing https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs.  It's free.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great install guide that includes the steps to solve the issue above.

https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-931127

The Oracle OCI libs need to be installed and this guide will show you how.

Answer (score 0):

By installing windows build tools as below all the gyp errors will be resolved

npm install -g --production windows-build-tools

Hope it will be helpful for someone